# how do i stop Timeout from running if condition changes/updates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

code:

```js
const isEnd = false; // Whenever event triggers the value will be false.

if (isEnd) {
console.log('Manual End')
} else {
setTimeout(() => {
console.log('Automatic End')
}, 30000);
}
```

Issue:

- This is event, so when the event triggers `isEnd` value will be `false` and when event triggers it has 30 seconds to update value to `true`.
- `isEnd` value can be changed to `true`, Anytime by the user/me in running app or without restarting.
- If `isEnd` values changes to `true` in a given time (30 seconds) I want to log manual end and remove setTimeout and don't log amything inside setTimeout function.

I tried until now:

- tried if/else, switch, while, do while.
- tried to clearTimeout and a lot different ways but can't remove setTimeout

```js
import { setTimeout as wait } from 'node:timers/promises';

  let timerId;
  switch (isEnded) {
    case true:
      console.log('Manual Ended');

      clearTimeout(timerId);
      break;
    case false:
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      timerId = wait(30000).then(() => {
        console.log('Automatic Ended');
      });
      break;
  }
```

excepted:

- if condition updates log `manual End`
- if condition doesn't changes it should only log `Automatic End`
- should log only any one of two logs.

Comment: I think there's some erroneus logic in your code. You check if `isEnd` is true/false **only at the beginning** and, based on this check, your code will decide if console.log or set the timer. If you then change `isEnd` to a new value, you need to re-run your check on it and - if it's the case - stop the timer.

Comment: Kind of Yes, this is event whenever this event starts it's (isEnd) default value is `false` but this can be changes to `true` in given time @cheesyMan

Comment: So, haow your code will know that `isEnd` changed to true?

Comment: I think your case is in [this document](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#cancelling-timers)

Comment: i even tried checking `isEnd` values changed to true by another setTimout

Comment: setImmediate()? does it check  if it's value has changed? @NickVu

Comment: I'm wondering if you're using the same library? `signal` is from `AbortController`. I'm not sure the entire setup of yours but it seems promising for your case @DreamyPlayer

Comment: Yes same ig, for setTimeout or other things i use `node:timers/promises`... @NickVu

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to trigger changes in the value of `isEnd` you can try a different approach,

you can directly `clearTimeOut` whenever you or the user change the value of `isEnd`

for example instead of doing this

```
const isEnd = false 
let timerId;

buttn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  isEnd = true
})



if (isEnd) {
  console.log('Manual End')
  clearTimeOut(timerId)
} else {
timerId = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Automatic End')
}, 30000);
}
```

do this

```
let timerId =  setTimeout(automaticEnd, 30000);
// when the user make a manual break 
cancelButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  manualEnd()
})



function automaticEnd() {
  console.log('Automatic End')
}

function manualEnd() {
  clearTimeOut(timerId)
  console.log("manualEnd")
}
```

Comment: tried this now but i'm still getting both logs - if i updated value to `true` it logs manual after 30 seconds it's even logging Automatic End

Comment: and this has no big defference to what i have tried...

Comment: I tried my example locally and it is works fine

Comment: in my example I didn't use variable to store the state like `isEnd`, I just clear the timer directly when the action happens

Answer (score 0):

You could try a somehow more complex but interesting and elegant approach, using an *object structure* for your condition `isEnd`, and using object [`getters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [`setters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) to subscribe to a custom *listener* for object property changes:

This works perfectly in browser console (you can launch the snippet), should work in Node as well:

```js
// Object of your condition
const isEnd = {
  _value: false, // this is the value of the condition
  valueListener: function(val) {}, // defining a generic listener

  // getter
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  },

  // setter
  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.valueListener(val); // when changing the value, the function valueListener is called with the new value set
  },

  // method to pass an actual listener function to valueListener property
  listenTo: function(listener) {
    this.valueListener = listener;
  }
};

console.log("START: isEnd has a value of: " + isEnd.value);


// timer of 20 seconds
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Timer expired');
}, 20000)

// you subscribe to the isEnd.value change, passing an actual listener function
// this function should contain the logic to execute
// based on the new condition value
// (like clearing the timer)
isEnd.listenTo(function(val) {
  console.log('new value for isEnd is now: ' + val);

  if (val === true) {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log('timer cleared!');
    }
  }

  if (val === false) {
    console.log('HEY... false again!');
  }
})

// timer of 5 seconds that simulates
// the condition changing after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  isEnd.value = true;
}, 5000)

// timer of 10 seconds that simulates
// the condition changing after
// another 5 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  isEnd.value = false;
}, 10000)
```

Comment: for some reason the part at `new value` changed to true after given time it changed to false again and i got logs of both Thanks for effort

Comment: IF you're talking of my snippet, it's my code that is changing it back again to false (I set up 2 fake timers) :))) The last 2 `setTimeout()` are just fake, simulating the user changing the condition, you should not copy them.

Comment: in the end those 2 fake timers i tried without them and it logs timer expired 2 times and i got the log that value is changed

Comment: and btw time is custom could be anything  30s 1m 2days... or maybe i little messed with you code snippet i'm trying again and Just node app not browser app

Comment: Really don't know. In my snippet the only thing that changes the condition are the 2 fake `setTimeout()`. Clearly there is something else in your code that changes it (but I cannot say what), only you know :)

Comment: i removed 2 fake timers and tested with dynamic `value: isEnd` and custom time in constant `timer` but if value changes to true it logs 2 times `timer expired` and it's not reaching to `listenTo` funtion

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code and how you're trying to implementing my solution inside your overall code, so I can't tell anything about it. The snippet alone surely work as it is intended to work, but clearly it depends on you to try fitting it properly inside your project (if it can be done, anyway).